# Prism for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) Apps

Tags: c#, prism, uwp

I would like to upgrade a (c#) Windows Store App for Windows 8.1 to UWP. The project in build on Prism and I can't find a suitable Prism Nuget Package for UWP.
Can Prism for WPF or Windows Store Apps be used for UWP?
Is there any Prism version for UWP available? 
Shall we expect any future version?

Comment: I disagree with bluefeet closing this as too broad.  The questions were yes or no questions which resulted in one reasonably short answer.

Answer (score 7):

Check this out https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism

They ported Prism to UWP ^^ so don't use nuget package at the mean while but download the solution and build it then reference it in your project > HAVE FUN ^^

Comment: Ibrahim, Thanks alot!

Comment: That's the right answer :) A NuGet package should be available soon.